# SSIS: how to determine column count in conditional split

Tags: ssis

I am working in SSIS.  I am splitting a pipe-delimited, quote-qualified flat file into separate flat files.  The flat file is ragged, i.e., the number of columns varies because of different record types.  I have 3 record types -- A, B, and C.  A has 2 columns, B has 3 columns, and C has 4 columns.  The flat file connection manager has only 1 column defined `[Column 0]` (in which I read the entire row as 1 column) to allow for column counting.  I have a conditional split after the flat file source that determines if each record type has the correct number of columns.  Those records with deficient / surplus columns get written to an error flat file.  My condition for each record type is pretty simple:

`LEN([Column 0]) - LEN( REPLACE([Column 0], "|", "") ) != x`

where x is the given record type's column count minus 1.  (For example, since C has 4 columns, I expect C to have 3 pipe characters as column delimiters.  So, for C, `x = 3`.)

The problem I'm running into is that this does not account for the file being quote-qualified, i.e., I am erroneously replacing pipe characters that are part of each column's string (as long as that string is wrapped by quotation marks).

Is there a way to avoid counting the quote-qualified pipe characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is quote qualified, instead of splitting using the regular pipe `|` we can split for the pipes in between columns, which is  `"|"`.

So the conditional split expression becomes (by using the escape sequence `\"` for quotes and replacing that with an arbitrary 1 length character such as `x`:

`LEN([Column 0]) - LEN(REPLACE([Column 0],"\"|\"","xx")) != x`